# What should resource identifier be for legacy/on-prem API when trying to aquire JWT from AAD using ADAL.NET

Tags: oauth, azure-active-directory, adal

I have a legacy/on-prem API that I need to be protected by OAuth to Azure Active Directory.

The API is counsumed by trusted applications that can obtain JWT using client credentials as follows:

```
var context = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant-id>");
var credentials = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
var result = await context.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceIdentifier, credentials);
```

Using the AcquireTokenAsync(String, ClientCredential) [overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory.authenticationcontext.acquiretokenasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_IdentityModel_Clients_ActiveDirectory_AuthenticationContext_AcquireTokenAsync_System_String_Microsoft_IdentityModel_Clients_ActiveDirectory_ClientCredential_), which requires a resource identifier and client credentials.

What is the resource identifier that I should use?
Assume my legacy/on-prem API that I want protected is hosted at https://test.qwerty.com.au/api/v2/resource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hosting address does not matter.
It excepts one of two things:

1. The API client id/application id
2. The App ID URI

The first one you can get from the Overview of the app registration for the API, the second from the Expose an API tab.

So it wants an identifier for the API.

As an additional note, make sure you register at least 1 application permission to the API as well, and grant it to your client apps. 
This will prevent an attack on your API. 
https://joonasw.net/view/always-check-token-permissions-in-aad-protected-api

Answer (score 1):

Adding to @juunas's answer, there should be 2 apps registered in your tenant. One is for your Web API, the other one is for the consumer.

Firstly, you need to configure to protect your Web API with Azure AD. For this step, you may refer to: [JwtBearer configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-protected-web-api-app-configuration#jwtbearer-configuration). An easy way is to create a new Web API project, and choose to use "Work or School accounts" for authentication, then you will get a sample.

[image]

And, in the Startup class, it is set to validate the audience, which in my case is `https://hanxia.onmicrosoft.com/JackTestWebAPI_20191216090406`

[image]

The next step is to acquire a token:

[image]

Finally, you can use the token to call the Web API:

[image]

Comment: Though that said, it's possible to use just one app now as well, though I'm not sure how well it'll work with ADAL / v1.